# Can sqlmap be used on telnet?

Tags: sqlmap

Is there a way to use sqlmap over telnet or do I have to manually create a web wrapper that will send the payload over a parameter and output the response?

Comment: What do you want to do with it over telnet? Are you routing a direct connection to the DBMS over telnet, or wanting to scan something?

Comment: to scan something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQLmap has no native support for Telnet, and it's not clear that it would handle typical telnet (or similar protocol) responses in a useful way: it makes use of (among other things) the status code for responses, path components of the URL and encoding of HTTP parameters in request bodies. None of these would apply to a telnet connection.

You can use SQLmap to directly scan a database management system, using the `-d` switch, but this uses whatever protocol the DBMS uses, and tends to require credentials to access the DBMS.